# How can I replace a string by '$&'?

Tags: javascript

View the next code:

```
'<node>* loduis <node>*\nucla $&*'.replace(/\<node\>/g, '$&');
```

The result is:

```
'<node>* loduis <node>*\nucla <node>*'
```

rather than the expected

```
'$&* loduis $&*\nucla $&*'
```

Why is it not replacing `'<node>'` with `'$&'`?

Comment: so save the original string and don't do any replace operations on it...

Comment: If you want the original text, don't use `replace()` on it.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I'm sure OP is asking why the second replace fails, and how to make it succeed. Seems like a good question to me.

Comment: I see. The problem is that JS is interpreting '$&' as a back-reference.

Comment: I thought it was a fair question, asking why the second replace doesn't restore the string to what it originally was.

Comment: @Stijn: What do you mean? It fails because of the `$&` syntax in the second `.replace()`, and OP wants to know how to get around that.

Comment: It was not asked clearly, but it is a good question.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: Yeah, the code example could throw a person off. Would have been better to just drop the first `.replace()`, and have `<node>` in the string literal. I think OP was trying to demonstrate that it works one way, but not the other.

Comment: @BlueSkies It could be edited to make sense and actually state the question.

Comment: @BlueSkies My apologies, seems like the issue is more complex than I thought, in my defence the question wasn't very clear.

Comment: I'd vote to reopen, but I don't have enough rep. Also, I guess it's been answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must:

```
'$&* loduis $&*\nucla $&*'.replace(/\$&/g, '<node>')
                          .replace(/\<node\>/g, function () { return "$&"; });
```

`$&` inserts the matched string in `replace()`. ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter))

As mentioned in the comments, you can escape `"$&"` as `"$$&"`.

Comment: +1 This is the only way I could think of doing it. I wondered if there was an escape sequence that could be used, but I haven't found one.

Comment: You can also use `$$` to escape the `$` sign, e.g.: `replace(/\<node\>/g, '$$&');`

Comment: @Sam: Nice! I was about to go to the spec. Saved me a trip!

Comment: @Sam I prefer to write a few more characters that make code easier to read, but yes, being a regex question that's a viable answer.

Comment: Amazingly, the response time, thanks to all